# Was setTimer deprecated in Swift 3?

Tags: swift3, quick-nimble

I am trying to create a CocoaPod for Swift 3. Because CocoaPods uses [Nimble](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble) and [Quick](https://github.com/Quick/Quick), and those libraries haven't been updated yet, I forked the repos and am trying to convert them.

In the Nimble project there is a function called with the signature of:

```
setTimer(start: DispatchTime, interval: UInt64, leeway: UInt64)
```

The compiler says `Cannot invoke 'setTimer' with an argument list of type '(start: DispatchTime, interval: UInt64, leeway: UInt64)'`

```
private let pollLeeway: UInt64 = NSEC_PER_MSEC
let interval = UInt64(pollInterval * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
asyncSource.setTimer(start: DispatchTime.now(), interval: interval, leeway: pollLeeway)
```

The auto-complete shows all the setTimer methods are deprecated, but from what I [found](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0088-libdispatch-for-swift3.md) they shouldn't be.

Is there a replacement?

Answer (score 8):

In Swift 3.0 you should use

```
let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(flags: DispatchSource.TimerFlags(rawValue: UInt(0)), queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default))
    timer.scheduleRepeating(deadline: DispatchTime.init(uptimeNanoseconds: UInt64(100000)), interval: DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(1), leeway: DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(0))
```

to instead, and it's work for me

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 8 beta 1, the signature of that method is:

```
public func setTimer(start: DispatchTime, 
                  interval: DispatchTimeInterval, 
                    leeway: DispatchTimeInterval = default)
```

If you plug in the correct `DispatchTime` and `DispatchTimeInterval` parameters it will compile and you will see a deprecation warning:

```
'setTimer(start:leeway:)' is deprecated: replaced by 
instance method 'DispatchSourceTimer.scheduleOneshot(deadline:leeway:)'
```

As always, command+clicking on these Swift classes and methods will get you into the Swift interface sources where these methods are declared.